# Is PDO database connection secure?

Tags: php, database, pdo, connection

I am trying to connect to my database with the following code. And it works, but I am not sure how secure is it. Do I must have a private function too? I don't have any examples of how to apply a private function on this code.

```
$username = 'user';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=register';
$password = 'somepassword';

try{
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


}catch (PDOException $ex){
    echo "Connection failed ".$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is secure. How you query may be another matter entirely.

Comment: [Visibility modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) aren't about security. (Historically they're not about visibility either, ..)

Answer (score 0):

Better use php composer where you can put these details in a environment file .env. It will be secured as .env is hidden and is placed on Server.

Answer (score 0):

- Put the connection parameters into a secure place (i.e. not reachable
  by HTTP requests, something like the first answer will be nice), don't leave them into PHP script or some file in the same context... if you put there, protect it with htaccess DENY directive
- Never echo exceptions into script output, always deal with them (put
  into a log file, translate to friendly errors hiding parameters,
  etc). The script never should throw exceptions to the user, it must be handled... the user must only see friendly messages from the script, even a "Ops, something bad happen here..." is better than a "ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'users'" (that show the user a part of the database structure, witch is a security problem)